# Tampermonkey button click does not open popup

Tags: tampermonkey

I have a simple page with some form data which I want to fill. In my user script I have added a debugger; statement which breaks in the user script so that I can debug.

Issue is when I am debugging the user script via dev console, everything works. It click buttons to open the popup. Then fill in the fields etc...

However if I run it without debugger, nothing works. So I have added delays after each step and it still doesn't work. No errors either.

in summary to open popup;

```
        var btn = $("[aria-label='Add properties']");
        btn.focus();
        btn.click();
```

with debugger it works removing debugger it won't work.

To fill a textbox within the popup;

```
        hat = document.querySelectorAll('.myCtrl')[1];
        hat.focus();
        hat.value="Hat";
        delayMe(3000);
```

works with debugger.

I have tried below as well;

```
        hat = document.querySelectorAll('.myCtrl')[1];
        hat.focus();
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Hat');
        hat.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}));
```

This also works only with debugger.

Then I tried Selenium IDE to record the same steps and it works! Only thing is I can't use selenium since there are some logic which can't be done via Selenium

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I have too little rep:

Just to clarify -- does your page have any UI items that load late or won't load fully until a user action? I am curious because I've had issues where it would run before something actually loaded in(package related). So delaying the start of it helped.

I did also check if the element existed or was accessible before it tried to access it and change an attribute, value etc. That may be something you want to try.